# Point colours based on hover in R shiny and Rmarkdown

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, reactive

I would like to create a shiny plot in an Rmarkdown document where the colour of the points depend on the mouse pointer (hover). However, the desired plot only appears a fraction of a second until the hover element of the input list is set to `NULL` again. Why is this?

Example:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r,echo=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)

dfr <- data.frame(x, y)

give_col <- function(){
  if(is.null(input$hover$y)){
    rep(2, length(x))
  }else{
      (input$hover$y < dfr$y) + 1
    }}

imageOutput("image_id", hover = "hover")
textOutput("text_id")

output$image_id <- renderPlot({
  plot(dfr$x, dfr$y, col = factor(give_col()))
  # plot(dfr$x, dfr$y)  # Without col the give_col() element remains
                        # as can be seen in the output text
})
output$text_id <- reactive({paste(give_col())})
```
````

If you remove the colour part of the plot, the text output behaves as expected, so I guess it must be something with the plotting itself (same for `pch` instead of `col` or with `ggplot()` instead of `plot()`).

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because when you plot with the new color, it sends a hover event which reinitialize the color.

You can use `reactiveValue` together with `observeEvent` to store the values when the event appears:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
runtime: shiny
output: html_document
---

```{r,echo=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rnorm(100)

dfr <- data.frame(x, y)
give <- reactiveValues(col=rep(2, length(x)))
observeEvent(input$hover,{give$col <- (input$hover$y < dfr$y) + 1})

imageOutput("image_id", hover = "hover")
textOutput("text_id")

output$image_id <- renderPlot({
  plot(dfr$x, dfr$y, col = factor(give$col))
  # plot(dfr$x, dfr$y)  # Without col the give_col() element remains
                        # as can be seen in the output text
})
output$text_id <- reactive({paste(give$col)})
```
````

Comment: Why does the re-plotting that changes `input$hover` not also trigger the `observeEvent`? (that would mean that 'observeEvent' works differently from simple invalidations, would it not?)
answer can be found [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/observeEvent.html)